# Download speed is super slow after reinstalling Windows 10

Tags: internet, download, speed

Speeds I used to get before were somewhere around 1,5MB/s. My top speed now is 20KB/s (I tried downloading with multiple browsers).

Download speed in various applications has no problem with reaching 3MB/s.

What should I try before jumping off a bridge?

EDIT: I updated Windows, tried network reset and nothing changed.

Comment: You should perhaps try installing the drivers for the network device you're using instead of relying on whatever generic drivers Windows has.

Comment: Did you do all Windows Updates after reinstalling?  That would do some driver updates from the Microsoft Update Catalog.

Comment: This isn't really a solution to your problem, but it could help a bit with it. You can try disabling Nagle's Algorithm. If you'd like to learn more about what this does, this Wikipedia article could help you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm